# Generate all the possible permutations of a class

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have the following classes. For testing purpose, I would like to get all the possible permutations of the class Client. I know that the number can be very large, but this is not my problem for now.

Client: No (int), Name(string), Address(Address object)
Address: Street(string), Country(string), etc.

For a property of type int, I always try the same three values (-1, 0, 1), for string (null, string.Empty, "Hello World", etc.). For the base types, it works well. However, for the class Address, this is different.

In brief, I am trying to write a method generic enough to take any Type (class, etc.) and get all the possible permutations (in other words: public IEnumerable GetPermutations(Type myType)). With the help of .NET Reflection, this method would loop on all the settable properties.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: where do you get the values from? do you have a list of allowed values, for example?

Comment: @Aziz: He is asking for a brute force for each possible value.

Comment: How much work do you have done already?  What is the part you're having trouble with (ie. generating the permuations, storing the address info, using reflection, etc...)?

Comment: This has nothing to do with permutations. Look it up. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a class that may get you started, though I haven't tested it much.  Note that this will only work for classes that have a no-args constructor, and won't work for some types of recursive classes (e.g. a class with a property of its own type, such as a tree).  You also may want to pre-populate more classes in the static constructor.

```
public static class PermutationGenerator
{
    private static class Permutation<T>
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Choices { get; set; }
    }

    static PermutationGenerator()
    {
        Permutation<int>.Choices = new List<int> { -1, 0, 1 }.AsReadOnly();
        Permutation<string>.Choices = new List<string> { null, "", "Hello World" }.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> GetPermutations<T>()
    {
        if (Permutation<T>.Choices == null) {
            var props = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite);
            Permutation<T>.Choices = new List<T>(GeneratePermutations<T>(() => Activator.CreateInstance<T>(), props)).AsReadOnly();
        }
        return Permutation<T>.Choices;
    }

    private static IEnumerable GetPermutations(Type t) {
        var method = typeof(PermutationGenerator).GetMethod("GetPermutations", new Type[] {}).MakeGenericMethod(t);
        return (IEnumerable)(method.Invoke(null,new object[] {}));
    }

    private delegate T Generator<T>();

    private static IEnumerable<T> GeneratePermutations<T>(Generator<T> generator, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props)
    {
        if (!props.Any())
        {
            yield return generator();
        }
        else
        {
            var prop = props.First();
            var rest = props.Skip(1);

            foreach (var propVal in GetPermutations(prop.PropertyType))
            {
                Generator<T> gen = () =>
                {
                    var obj = generator();
                    prop.SetValue(obj, propVal, null);
                    return (T)obj;
                };
                foreach (var result in GeneratePermutations(gen, rest))
                {
                    yield return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 problems with this: 1) It's not really the question he asked (it fits the question title, but not the content).  2) Recursive solution isn't really the best idea in this case.  Read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302371.aspx

Comment: Wow! Amazing work! This is not perfect, but I have to say that I am impress. I want you in my team! :P

Comment: @Joel Coehorn - can you elaborate on 1?  If you call PermutationGenerator.GetPermutations<Client>() as in the question, you'll get a set of Client objects with all combinations of the different properties set, as requested.

Comment: @kvb -- In GetPermutations<T>, how would you handle cases such as byte[]? There is no parameterless constructor for byte[].

Comment: You have two options: first of all, if there's a fixed set of byte[] values that you always want to use, set Permutation.Choices<byte[]> to that list in the static constructor.  Otherwise, you'll need to extend the code a bit; how you do this will depend on what you want the code to do in that case.

Answer (score 4):

The [PEX](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/) testing framework does something along the lines. It attempts to provide several permutations of method parameters such that potentially useful test cases are covered.

Answer (score 1):

Most non-trivial dynamically allocated objects -- like strings -- don't have a finite amount of different "permutations" they can be in.  That string can be as long as you want until your RAM runs out.

So this is really a completely Sisyphean task, and there's no point going on with it as stated unless you put a lot more heavy restrictions on what kind of permutations you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at PEX

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/default.aspx

It's a whitebox test generation tool which integrates in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As many have said, generating all permutations is computationally infeasible for non-trivial classes.  What I have had to do, and had great success with, is generating all permutations of a class for a specific range of inputs;  i.e., given a class with properties A, B, and C, I'd like to generate all permutations of A=1, A=2, B=1, C=3, and C=4, resulting in:

A=1, B=1, C=3

A=2, B=1, C=3

A=1, B=1, C=4

A=2, B=1, C=4

This kind of thing can be accomplished with recursive algorithms or some really elegant LINQ queries.  There's a fairly exhaustive piece on that [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/selectmany-probably-the-most-p), but its a good amount of programming and it really helps if you're boned up on your Set Theory.

Answer (score -1):

That's like asking to move the Great Wall of China in 1 hour, into space. It cannot be done.

You would need to know what defines each permutation of every type, even types you didn't create, and that's impossible.

Comment: you can move the Great Wall of China into space in 1 hour ... if you have the resources :P

Comment: Yeah, and you can technically do it using recursion and reflection, but that would be horrible to look at and slow. And the only use would be for testing, and I don't see how testing every possible permutation would be helpful.